# Can we include a "Section" in either managed or unmanaged package?

Tags: page-layout, package

I have created an unmanaged package. I am wondering if a "Section" (the sections which we usually created in "Edit Layout") can be included in a package? Or do we have to create a section manually in the org where the package would be deployed?

Comment: The overall layout is named but a section within is not. So you can include a layout but not a section for use in the org where the package is installed.

Comment: Hi @Keith pls make this an answer so we can get the question closed and work on our sfse stats :-)

Comment: @guy should have - done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall layout is named but a section within is not.

So you can include a layout in your package and pick it by name and use it in the org where the package is installed. But sections are not separately usable - they come only as part of an overall layout.